# Search for a String in an Access Table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Table Name: MissingT
Field Name : "Case Information"
String to find in each row : "WEBID:"

In this table under Field "Case Information",  I want to find the word "WEBID:" in each row and get the next 4 letter following it.

That 4 letters should be written in the other field "WebId"

I have to do this for each row till the EOF.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the query design interface to search for that string using 'Like'? Then you can expand upon that to get your answer.

Comment: Each row has the word "WEBID:" in "Case Information" fiels. But the 4 letters following "WEBID:" will be different on each row. I just want to capture that 4 letters and update "WEBID" field with it on the same row.

Comment: Have you tried using the query design interface to search for that string using 'Like'? Once you find the rows, the rest can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the below. Do you really mean the 'next 4 letter' or do you mean 'next 4 characters'?  If you want to test, just change the query to a select query and make the 'Mid(....' a column in the query.

```
UPDATE MissingT 
SET MissingT.WebID = Mid([Case Information],(InStr(1,[Case Information],'webid:')+7),4)
WHERE (((MissingT.[Case Information]) Like '*webid:*'));
```

Comment: Normally the Case information will have something like "[WBID:J4XF] Create account(s)". I just want to get J4XF and update WEBID field with it. I tried your sql script in query update, and get no records updated.

Comment: Since you never mentioned the exact format (spaces, alignment, etc.) it is difficult to make an assumption. I assumed there was a space after 'webid: ". Change the +7 to +6 if no space.

Comment: there is no space in-between "Webid:" and the 4 text following it. Anyhow, I tried both +7 and +6 and still getting no records updated.

Comment: Do you know how to create a SELECT query to look for the records you want? I created test data with various combinations (upper/lower case, leading/trailing spaces, etc.) and it works just fine. Please post what YOU have created to look for the matching records. If you can't find 'em, you can't update 'em!

Comment: HOLY COW!!! No wonder you can't find a match!!  If you provided accurate info in your original question, we would be finished now. Hint: is it 'WEBID' or 'WBID'????? (Your sample = "[WBID:J4XF] Create account(s)")

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. It is supposed to be WEID and not WEBID. I just changed it and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did fail to see that the test string could be other than the first characters in the field. So using InStr() would be necessary to get the index of where the characters you were after would be located, as did the answer after mine.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking something along the lines

```
 UPDATE MissingT
 SET WebId = Mid$([Case Information], 7)
 WHERE Left$([Case Information], 7) = "WEBID:";
```

It has been a while, but I seem to recall that these functions are available in a query.

If you omit the 3rd argument to Mid(), it returns all from the location of the 2nd Arg, to the end.

The WHERE also could be:

```
  WHERE [Case Information] LIKE "WEBID:*"
```

I think.

Comment: When I run this in a query Update, I could not get any record to update. It gives "You are about to update 0 row(s)

Comment: Because it should be 'Left$([Case Information], 6)'  not 7. Why not run as a select query first to see what it would look like?

Comment: Same here, I tried both 6 and 7 with this code and get 0 records updated.